# Javascript - how to declare namespace objects using new conventions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, conventions

I am a big fan of latest programming conventions and latest additions to programming languages. Recently I read in [Google Guidelines](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-use-const-and-let) that we should use `const` and `let` instead of `var`.

Now in my project I have namespace object variables (if that's what they are called, correct me please if I am wrong) like this

```
var myObj = {

    func1: {},
    func2: {}
};

var myOtherObj = {

    var1: 'foo',
    var2: 'bar'
};
```

How should I name these objects now using the new conventions, with `const` or with `let`? I am confused because I don't know if these big objects change over time, or not...

Comment: Change them to `const` and run the code. If it breaks because something wants to modify the variables, either fix that or else change it to `let`.

Comment: the thing is I don't quite understand what it means for a big object like this to change, if it's a simple local variable, then its easy to see if it get's changed or not

Comment: The `const` declaration does not make the **object** immutable; it makes the **variable** immutable.

Comment: Don't use namespace objects; use ES6 modules.

Comment: @Gothdo what is that and why should I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` doesn't prevent objects from changing (said otherwise it doesn't [*freeze*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) them). It prevents the value of variables to change.

For example you can still do

```
const myObj = {

    func1: {},
    func2: {}
};
```

and then

```
myObj.fun3 = function(){...
```

What you can't do with a variable declared with `const` (but which doesn't seem to be your will) is

```
myObj = {};
```

Modules are usually declared with `const`.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule I try to follow is:  `const` everywhere you can, `let` when you can't use `const` and `var` never.

In the case of your example, when you are defining objects (or in other cases arrays, etc.), I tend to define those with `let` to give a clear indication that either the variable reference could change *or* the contents inside.

`const` will not prevent properties of objects or elements in a list from being changed, so if you're unsure if thats going to happen, its best to use `let` in my opinion.  It's more clear and could prevent confusion down the road.

Comment: what if in my example myOtherObj.var1 changes value many times in runtime? Will it work if myOtherObj is declared as const?

Comment: Yes, that will still work, but its semantically confusing.  Like I said, `const` won't prevent object properties or list elements from being changed, it just prevents the assignment of the variable reference.  So, in your case, if the contents of the object `myOtherObj` can change many times, using `let` is a clear indication of your intent.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a symbol that can't change value to refer to an object that is also immutable, you can do this:

```
const CONSTANT = Object.freeze({
  a: "hello",
  b: "world"
});
```

Also bear in mind that older platforms are still out there that won't support `const` and `let` (and probably `Object.freeze()` for that matter).